# Django async with AppConfig.ready sync/async

Tags: django, asynchronous, ready

I am running Django version 4.2.4 in async mode. For one of my apps I have some code to run on ready like this:

```
class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'demo.core'

    def ready(self):
        from .utils import my_sync_func
        my_sync_func()
```

When I run this code, I get the warning "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'CoreConfig.ready' was never awaited"

When I use sync_to_async like this:

```
class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'demo.core'

    async def ready(self):
        from .utils import my_sync_func
        await sync_to_async(my_sync_func)()
```

I get the warning "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'CoreConfig.ready' was never awaited"

What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you ever got an answer on this? Running into the same problem.